# Stack Exchange account instead of OpenID

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, openid

I am currently using OpenID connected with a Yahoo email address. I want to create a normal Stack Exchange account and connect it with my current account. I don't want to use Yahoo OpenID any more.
Is it possible?

I could not find a way to do it.